# Implementing std::is_invocable_r with C++ 20 concepts

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I am trying to implement `std::is_invocable<R, Callable, Args...>` using C++ 20's concepts with as little help from STL as possible and without using `std::invoke` etc.

This is my current approach. It causes compile error though (msvc):
`error C3864: 'is_invocable_r': requires clause is incompatible with the declaration`

```cpp
template<class R, class Fn, class... ArgTypes>
    requires requires(Fn fn, ArgTypes... arg_types)
    {
        { std::forward<Fn>(fn)(std::forward<ArgTypes>(arg_types)...) } -> std::same_as<R>;
    }
struct is_invocable_r : std::true_type {};

template<class R, class Fn, class... ArgTypes>
struct is_invocable_r : std::false_type {};
```

What would be the propper way of doing this?

Comment: What's `same<R>`?

Comment: It's equivalent to std::same_as, I've updated the code.

Comment: "*without using std::invoke etc*" That's a contradiction. `invocable` *requires* `std::invoke` to exist. It's *based on* `std::invoke`. Also, you should not re-implement concepts like this. The standard library provides concepts for a reason.

Comment: I've never argued that it should be done. I'm doing it for the learning purpose. That being said, I didn't want a simple implementation like `requires(...) { std::invoke(...) } -> R` that's why I've explicitly said that I don't want it used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems.

1. You aren't specializing the template. You are re-declaring it. A partial specialization must be declared with a template-id. I.e. `is_invocable_r<...>`.
2. A partial specialization should be *more* constrained than the primary template declaration, not less. And it must be a more specialized case of the primary too parameter-wise; we can't just repeat the exact same list of arguments and call it a specialization.

With that in mind, a simpler way to define your trait could be:

```
template<class R, class Fn, class... ArgTypes>
struct is_invocable_r :
    std::bool_constant<
        requires(Fn fn, ArgTypes... arg_types)
        {
            { std::forward<Fn>(fn)(std::forward<ArgTypes>(arg_types)...) } -> std::same_as<R>;
        }
    > 
{};
```

Since all the template parameters must be provided explicitly, and there is no room to specialize your class template (can't add arguments after a parameter pack in a class template), we can't specialize at all.

Instead, we just feed the result of the `requires` expression into `bool_constant`, since it's the result of the expression that ultimately decides the value of the trait<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> - Your requires expression doesn't cover pointers-to-members, so it's not equivalent to the result `std::is_invocable_r` gives. More refinement (maybe even via specialization) is required to cover that case.